# nav pills navigation html takes double clicks to change active tab class

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
      <div class="container">
                <br>
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class=" active btn-primary "><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Ask</a></li>
                    <li class=" btn-primary "><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Reviews</a></li>
                    <li class=" btn-info " ><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">WRITE A REVIEW</a></li>
                    <li class=" btn-info "><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">ASK A QUESTION</a></li>
                </ul>
                <br>

                <div class="tab-content">

                    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                       some content tab 1           
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
                                some content tab 2          
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
                            some content tab 3          
                    </div>
                    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
                            some content tab 4          
                    </div>
              </div>
        </div>
```

It takes double clicks on a tab to change the active tab from one to another.... the tab content changes on one click but the active tab is shown as home tab and changes only on second click on same tab.

P.S. I am using angular

Comment: give me the plunker

Comment: it works on plunker but not in my code, could angularjs be the reason behind the problem? @nareshvadlakonda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use **data-target** instead of **href** as when you use href your url also changes.. and the url of your current page changes..

Comment: anytime.. @UTSAVBHAGAT